# How to add row to data on Google Chart Tools?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, google-visualization

I am trying to create Google Chart on my ASP.NET MVC application. I am taking data from database and trying to put on chart. The problem is I could not add row to data. I am not able to add row inside ASP.NET code.

```
    @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                @item.Name
                @item.Quantity
//I am not able to write like this here: data.addrow(@item.Name, @item.Quantity)
            }
```

I am trying to add new rows like this:

```
data.addRows([
          ['Mushrooms', 3],
          ['Onions', 1],
          ['Olives', 1],
          ['Zucchini', 1],
          ['Pepperoni', 2]
        ]);
```

View structure:
Asp.net code
 Javascript
  Asp.net code
 Javascript
Asp.net code

My question is how to add new row in Javascript using data from model?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem is that you don't know how to send data to Google charts?

You can always just build the string with all the data in controller and send that to google charts. Use string builder in controller and load it to javascript then give that to data.addrows

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This is very important for me. Can you show one example please